# In python, how can records be grouped together based on multiple fields?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm familiar with grouping records together based on a single field by:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
rows.sort(key=itemgetter('some_field')

groups_list = []
for data, items in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter('some_field'):
    group_list = []
    for item in items:
        group_list.append(item)
    groups_list.append(group_list
```

If I wanted to group the records together based on two fields without having to iterate over them twice, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function to sort and group on those two fields:

```
f = lambda x: (x['field1'], x['field2'])
rows.sort(key=f)

groups_list = []
for data, items in groupby(rows, key=f):
     ...
```

Or update your `itemgetter` to fetch those two fields:

```
f = itemgetter('field1', 'field2')
rows.sort(key=f)

groups_list = []
for data, items in groupby(rows, key=f):
     ...
```